# The correct and optimal way to check language and print field depending on language, without affecting performance

Tags: theming, performance, i18n-l10n

I have a multilingual site, and for many reasons (don't ask why) I'm not using the Entity Translation module. Instead, I have 3 separate description fields for each language, and I want to print those depending on the current language. I just wanted to ask if this is the correct and optimal way to print render those fields, and whether or not it will have major implications on site's performance?

Inside my custom **node--content-type.tpl.php** at the top I put:

```
<?php hide($content['field_description_nl']); ?>
<?php hide($content['field_description_fr']); ?>
<?php hide($content['field_description_en']); ?>
```

and later inside the **teaser** and then again inside the **full node** I've put:

```
<?php 
global $language;
$lang_name = $language->language;
if($lang_name == "nl") {print render($content['field_description_nl']);}
if($lang_name == "fr") {print render($content['field_description_fr']);}
if($lang_name == "en") {print render($content['field_description_en']);}
?>
```

Will this work or will it dramatically slow down the site when the traffic starts pouring in?

Comment: I don't think we really can answer. I made similar tricks in Drupal 6, but it was [Boost](https://drupal.org/project/boost)ed site so performance cost was negligible. And I prefer `switch` over a series of `if`s, seems more natural to me. Also allows for easier defaults. One problem with it is - all 3 fields will always be loaded. Now, will it hit you, depends on too many things to know. DB performance, data size, used text filters, caching et cetera.

Answer (score 5):

That's a reasonable way of implementing an alternative language switcher for specific field output.

To keep the logic out of the template, you could add it to [`hook_preprocess_node`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) instead.

e.g:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_node
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables){
  global $language;
  $lang_field_name = 'field_description_'. $language->language;
  if(!empty($variables[$lang_field_name])){
    $variables['description'] = render($variables[$lang_field_name]);
  }
}
```

Then you can just use `print $description` in the `node--content-type.tpl.php` file.

Make sure your cache is different for each language.

See also [`field_attach_preprocess`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_preprocess/7) for how field language translations are added in core.

Comment: Thanks David Thomas,  I included your code inside my template.php's preprocess_node, and inside the node--content-type.tpl.php I added <?php print $description; ?> , but it returned an error Notice: Undefined variable: description in include() (line 71 of node--content-type.tpl.php

Comment: check `$variables['description']` is populated. The code may need tweaking.

Comment: I did <?php if ($description): ?>
<?php print $description; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
but it still brings that error and no results.

Comment: Check in the preprocess function, not the tpl. You may need to var_dump `$variables` to find correct field names to use there.

Comment: I think, I'll just forget about it var_dump and all that is way over my head.  I'm not really a professional coder.  I just hope that my original solution from the .tpl is not going to slow the site down when 15,000-50,000 daily visitors come to see a front page with the a view of 40 teasers each with that kind of language negotiation/selection in their node--content-type.tpl.php file.  I think the correct and more scalable way would be to do it your wayinside the template.php or through a module, but my coding skills are just not that good.

Comment: OK, your earlier method would also work fine. `if/else` statements are very fast in PHP.